# Append different shapes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to make a force graph with 2 types of shapes as nodes: `rect` and `circle`, the shape information is in `d.shape`. There are several threads out there, but the solutions are not very clear to me.

I tried first to use `merge` method, which does not work: in this [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/detotiqidi/1/edit?html,output), `var circlesANDrects = rects` shows rectangles and `var circlesANDrects = circles` shows circles, whereas `var circlesANDrects = circles.merge(rects)` does not show both.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Otherwise, I think the idea solution would be to use one block and `append` different shapes according to the shape information:

```
var circlesANDrects = svg.append("g").selectAll("rect circle")
.data(force.nodes())
.enter()
<!-- a function that appends different shapes according to shape information -->
```

Does anyone know how to add cases / condition to `append`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a function as an argument to `append`. According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_append):

> If the specified type is a string, appends a new element of this type (tag name) as the last child of each selected element [...] Otherwise, the type may be a function which is evaluated for each selected element

The problem is, if you use a function, you cannot simply return "circle" or "rect", like this:

```
.append(function(d){
    if(d.shape == "rect"){ 
        return "rect";
    } else {
        return "circle";
    }
});//this don't work...
```

Instead, you have to return the DOM element, something like this:

```
.append(function(d){
    if(d.shape == "rect"){ 
        return document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
    } else { 
        return document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
    }
});//this works...
```

As it is a little complicated, an easier solution (but not exactly following what you asked) is simply using a [symbol](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Shapes.md#symbol) here:

```
var circlesOrRects = svg.append("g").selectAll(".foo")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol()
    .type(function(d) { return d.shape == "rect" ? "circle" : "square"; }))
    .call(force.drag);
```

Here is your Bin: https://jsbin.com/povuwulipu/1/edit

Comment: But what if I want to specify some `attr` (e.g., `width` and `height`) that belong to `rect` but not `circle`?

Comment: Unfortunately, the "square" symbol has no `width` or `height`, just `size`. But you can set the size of the different symbols (circle, square, etc...) using a function.

Comment: So we can only specify the common attr of circle and square here?

Comment: No, you can set different shapes, sizes, colours etc... but the "square" is a "square", 4 equal sides.

Answer (score 1):

So, by the understanding the tick method in force layout.
tick method is a call back of force when each updation. 
So, we need to update both rect and circle separately in your case. Because, You created and stored the circle and rect into two variables.

the working version of your code is here: https://jsbin.com/disayafube/1/edit?html,output